# How to create a CloseableReference with Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

i want to create a CloseableReference when i implement a PlatformBitmapFactory
the method .of have two implements, if i use the first one

```
private PlatformBitmapFactory bmpFactory = new PlatformBitmapFactory() {
        @Override
        public CloseableReference<Bitmap> createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig) {
            CloseableReference<Bitmap> cr = CloseableReference
                    .of(Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, bitmapConfig));

            return cr;
        }
    };
```

it would be a compile error:
of(java.io.CloseableReference & android.graphics.Bitmap) in CloseableReference cannot be applied to (android.graphics.Bitmap)

But if i use the second one, i dont know how to make a ResourceReleaser .(actually its a interface , a super class of CloseableReference)

how should i put parameter in .of method?

edit:

What I want to achieve is create a reference of Bitmap but do not consume my app's memory(just like DraweeView do).
And I have two demands:

One is : get a reference of some new bitmap, same as `Bitmap.createBitmap()`, I would save their reference in a List, and then take the reference, further get them, additional draw some thing on them.(more than once)

Two is : get a reference of a drawable and it should be a bitmap, same as `BitmapFactory.decodeXXX()`. I would save its reference in a global variable, and then take the reference, further get it, use it Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Bitmap);(more than once too)

Now I try to do like one of implements of PlatformBitmapFactory `ArtBitmapFactory`

```
int sizeInBytes = BitmapUtil.getSizeInByteForBitmap(width, height, bitmapConfig);
    Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapPool.get(sizeInBytes);
    Bitmaps.reconfigureBitmap(bitmap, width, height, bitmapConfig);
    return CloseableReference.of(bitmap, mBitmapPool);
```

but memory increased.

Comment: and what the '&' mean in parameter?

Comment: You need to give us more context on what exactly you are trying to achieve. You should probably not deal with PlatformBitmapFactory directly.